# Can I use the word "sense" in this case?

Tags: nouns

I'm writing an article and I'm in doubt about the sentence below. Basically, *uncanny valley* "is a hypothesized relationship between the degree of an object's resemblance to a human being and the emotional response to such an object" (taken from Wikipedia). I decided to use the word "sense" after it, but I don't know if it works well after an established term like that, or if it sounds too casual. What do you say?

"Developers try to make facial animations look real without eliciting that uncanny valley sense."

Comment: elicit a sense? One elicits a response to something.

Comment: So would elicit be inappropriate in this case? What word should I use?

Comment: without eliciting uncanny valley feelings in viewers.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any confusion about what "sense" means in this context, so it appears you're asking us to proofread your sentence for *style*. Such questions are off-topic on this site, but I suggest you go to our sibling site [Writing.se] and look up "is this on-topic" in the Help Centre. It might be a better (and more productive!) place to ask questions about writing.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that sounds perfectly formal to me; but if you’re remotely unsure, you could rewrite it as "Developers try to make facial animations look real without eliciting that sense of uncanny valley." which I think reads as slightly more formal – either way, I think it’s fine to use the word "sense" in the same way you might use the word "feeling" in the sentence, “without causing a feeling of awkwardness”. Awkwardness is an established term, and so you could remove the word “feeling”, shortening the sentence to “without causing awkwardness”; but as the sentence is specifically discussing the *experience* of uncanny valley (like the experience of feeling awkwardness), I think using “sense” makes the sentence more clear, especially as "uncanny valley" isn't the most well-known term.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot! That was very helpful! One more question: a user above suggested that "elicit" sounds strange in this sentence. What do you think?

Comment: No problem. In response to the idea of "elicit" being used correctly for "eliciting a response", I personally would take it as the response elicited *is* the "sense of uncanny valley".